# How to create a Tensorflow dataset for inferencing (not training) for fashion_mnist-trained model from an arbitrary input JPG/PNG image

Tags: keras, tensorflow

OK so what I am trying to do is make a inference.py TensorFlow script that will load a saved model that has already been trained, take an input .jpg image, perform inferencing on it (on the existing model) and then print the prediction result to the screen.

Here is the train.py script that I ran to build my model in the first place:

```
# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(tf.__version__)

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

train_images.shape

len(train_labels)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(train_images[0])
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid(False)
# plt.show()


train_images = train_images / 255.0

test_images = test_images / 255.0


plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(train_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[train_labels[i]])
# plt.show()

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)

print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)

model.summary()

# Save the weights
model.save_weights('./checkpoints/my_checkpoint')
```

This works and produces a checkpoint file as expected (and is based on Tensorflow docs).  OK now for the harder part - I want to take an arbitrary .JPG or .PNG input file and then run inferencing on it.  So far I have created inference.py that looks like this:

```
# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

# Restore the weights
model.load_weights('./checkpoints/my_checkpoint')


probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([model, 
                                         tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])

### How do I make a dataset to pass in here from a .jpg?

predictions = probability_model.predict(  ...  )
```

So how do I actually create a dataset based on a single image and pass it into the predict() function?  Note that this image could have any size/resolution and will not have any transforms applied to it.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!